# `polygon edge not found` with the `xkcd` package

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, fonts, installation

I am trying to make 'xkcd' plot with the package 'xkcd'. I followed the `vignette("xkcd-intro")` to install 'xkcd' (font and package). I only had to add a path to `font_import` otherwise it would return an error.

```
library(extrafont)
download.file("http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf",
  dest="xkcd.ttf", mode="wb")
system("mkdir ~/.fonts")
system("cp xkcd.ttf ~/.fonts")
font_import(path="~/", pattern = "[X/x]kcd", prompt=FALSE)
loadfonts()
```

I made sure 'xkcd' is listed in the fonts

```
'xkcd' %in% fonts()
TRUE
```

I installed and imported the package 'xkcd'

```
install.packages('xkcd')
require(xkcd)
```

and I tried a simple plot

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=wt)) + geom_point() // works fine


ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=wt)) + geom_point() + theme_xkcd() // Return following error

Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
3: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
4: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
5: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
```

Can you help me with that?

---

I am on Mac OS X

```
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did

```
fonttable()
```

to find out where my other fonts where saved. They were all saved at `/Library/Fonts`. So, I simply moved my xkcd.ttf there

```
mv ~/.fonts/xkcd.ttf /Library/Fonts/
```

and I had to correct where the path was saved. To find out where the file was located I did

```
extrafont:::fonttable_file()
```

I then, opened this file and changed the path for `xkcd`. It works!